SharedMemory numpy array multiprocessing probelm
The problem
I have a lot of data that I first load in RAM with SharedMemory and then I read with many child-processes with multiprocessing.Pool.map.
The code
This is a simplified version (not really example complaint) that I am using:
def SharedObject: # wrapper of SharedMemory passed to subprocesses
  def __init__(self, blablabla):
    self.shmem = SharedMemory(create=True, size=numbers) # reference to shmem will live as long as the instance of the class will (shmem not getting GC)
    temp_arr = np.ndarray(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, buffer=self.shmem.buf)
    temp_arr[:] = ...lot of data... # this array will get destroyed after __init__ finishes

  def __getitem__(self, indices) -> np.ndarray: # used by subprocesses
    selected = np.ndarray(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, buffer=self.shmem.buf)
    return selected.__getitem__(indices)

# This is in main process
shobj = SharedObject()
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
  result= list(pool.map(f, shobj))  # f does shobj.__getitem__

The strange behavior
I have 64GBs of RAM in my pc. If I run the above algorithm with little data everything runs smoothly but if I load a lot (~40GBs) then I get the following error:
n __enter__
return self._semlock.__enter__()
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\mnandcharvim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 321, in _recv_bytes
waitres = _winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects(

(basically a lock misuse)
The data is only read so it would be better for me if I could load it in a read-only portion of memory so to not have locks. This question points out that SharedMemory is lock-free but at this point, based on the error that I get I am not sure).
2nd version
I also tried to conform the code more to the example of the official documentation that I linked:
shmems = [] # module variable (same module of SharedObject) as suggested in some answers
def SharedObject:
  def __init__(self, blablabla):
    shmem = SharedMemory(name=self.name, create=True, size=numbers) # this reference destroyed after __init__
    shmems.append(shmem) # but this one outlives it
    temp_arr = np.ndarray(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, buffer=self.shmem.buf)
    temp_arr[:] = ...lot of data...

  def __getitem__(self, indices) -> np.ndarray: # used by subprocesses
    shmem = SharedMemory(name=self.name) # added line
    selected = np.ndarray(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, buffer=shmem.buf)
    return selected.__getitem__(indices)

# This is in main process
shobj = SharedObject()
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
  result= list(pool.map(f, shobj))  # f does shobj.__getitem__

2nd strange behavior
This second version errors me out at shmem = SharedMemory(name=self.name) # added line saying that I do not have enough system resources to do mmap (weird thing as the data has already been mapped in RAM: the resources were enough for the supposedly first and one time only loading of it).
Things to keep in mind

Processing of the data involves only reads of it
I cannot use Threads (as with the content read I do non GIL-releasing calculations).
I just want to know a clear straighforward and functioning way for which I would be supposed to use SharedMemory in combination with numpy arrays and multiprocessing.
I need to read my data as numpy arrays

Minimal reproducible example
To reproduce properly adjust arguments  based on your system resources as to not overflow RAM. The example goes on deadlock in one of the main for loop iterations. Pressing CTRL+C shows the error.
I am using Python 3.12.2 64 bit on Windows 10.
script.py:
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

class SharedObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = (2000000, 2049)
        self.shmem = SharedMemory(create=True, size=2000000*8196)
        self.dtype = np.float32
        _temp_arr=np.ndarray(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, buffer=self.shmem.buf)
        _temp_arr[:] = [np.zeros(shape=2049, dtype=self.dtype) for j in range(2000000)]

def f(data: SharedObject) -> int:
    print("hello")
    return 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shobj = SharedObject()

    for j in range(20):
        print(j)
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            list(pool.map(f, [shobj]*256)) # 256 calls to f


Calls to close() are missing as well as unlink(). This can cause such issue. Besides, I wonder if this is safe to access data after shmem as been deleted (ref count to 0).

@JérômeRichard already tried including close() calls, ends up in error. Unlink() is called when main object gets destroyed and plus windows deletes automatically the memory that are not accessed anymore. Anyways, still missing a full comprehensive working code example.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example The code shown has multiple syntax errors

@SIGHUP attached as requested.

The code in the question is flawed.
Using a numpy array in shared memory in conjunction with multiprocessing is probably best explained by example.
In this example we create a one-dimensional numpy array of integers in shared memory. Each time the sub-process (process()) is called we add 1 to each element of the array.
Note the essential use of a lock to protect the shared memory while it's being modified.
process() is invoked NPROCS times. Therefore each element of the array should be equal to NPROCS once all processing has completed. We assert that this is True.
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock

SHM = "my_shared_memory_segment"
N = 1_000
DTYPE = int
NPROCS = 10_000

def process():
    global lock
    try:
        shm = SharedMemory(name=SHM)
        with lock:
            data = np.ndarray((N,), dtype=DTYPE, buffer=shm.buf)
            data[:] += 1
    finally:
        shm.close()

def init_lock(lock_):
    global lock
    lock = lock_

def main():
    try:
        lock = Lock()
        size = N * np.dtype(DTYPE).itemsize
        shm = SharedMemory(name=SHM, create=True, size=size)
        data = np.ndarray((N,), dtype=DTYPE, buffer=shm.buf)
        data.fill(0)
        pool = Pool(initializer=init_lock, initargs=(lock,))
        try:
            for _ in range(NPROCS):
                pool.apply_async(process)
        finally:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
        assert np.all(data == NPROCS)
    finally:
        shm.close()
        shm.unlink()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

You should be able to adapt this to suit your specific needs.
EDIT:
Apparently, there's a need for a rather large 2-dimensional ndarray as seen in code posted elsewhere.
Here is a significant edit to my original answer that deals with that requirement.
The code below runs without error on macOS 15.0.1 with Python 3.13.0
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

SHM = "my_shared_memory_segment"
N = 2_000_000
C = 2_048
DTYPE = np.float32
NPROCS = 256

def process(_):
    global lock
    try:
        shm = SharedMemory(name=SHM)
        with lock:
            data = get_array(shm)
            data[0][:] += 1
    finally:
        shm.close()

def init_lock(lock_):
    global lock
    lock = lock_

def get_array(shm):
    return np.ndarray((N, C), DTYPE, shm.buf)

def main():
    try:
        lock = Lock()
        size = N * C * np.dtype(DTYPE).itemsize
        shm = SharedMemory(name=SHM, create=True, size=size)
        data = get_array(shm)
        data.fill(0.0)
        with Pool(initializer=init_lock, initargs=(lock,)) as pool:
            pool.map(process, range(NPROCS))
    finally:
        shm.close()
        shm.unlink()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


After some tryouts I found a slight modification of your code (which remains complaint and multiprocessing safe) that though ends up in the same error. To produce the error you need both my memory size paramenters (or a lot of memory occupied relatively to the one of your system) and call to map instead of apply_async. Code: https://hastebin.com/share/anasadakod.csharp

@gcsar 2 things. 1) The code on hastebin doesn't run due to a missing import and 2) Your calculation for the shared memory segment size is dubious. If I fix the import then, even with the dubious calculation, your code runs without error on macOS 15.0.1 and Python 13.3.0. I would recommend size = N * C * np.dtype(DTYPE).itemsize

@gcsar Also, do you realise that in your hastebin code (because of your 2-dimensional ndarray) your shared memory segment is going to be ~16GB?

thank you for your efforts in trying to fix the issue. I can confirm to you that the code you provided copied and pasted on my machine ends up in the same error. It is hence a problem of my setup.

@gcsar Maybe your machine doesn't have enough virtual memory to handle an ndarray of that magnitude. Have you tried re-running the code with smaller values for N and/or C?

If decrement the shape parameters of the numpy array the code does work on my machine but I can't understand why as I have 64GBs of memory on my system and the data gets allocated in memory (I tracked the memory usage meanwhile the script is running). Moreover, the code errors at shm = SharedMemory(name=SHM) inside the subprocesses. At that point the data should have already been mapped and allocated in memory by the main process at shm = SharedMemory(name=SHM, create=True, size=size); data = get_array(shm); data.fill(0.0) (before any subprocess call)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
